# Как сделать так, чтобы телеграмм бот работал всегда, а не только тогда, когда у меня открыты файлы его кода?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Когда я закрываю файлы бота, он перестает работать, как это исправить?

Comment: У меня все боты работают на replit.com, вот статья: https://habr.com/ru/articles/709314/ у меня всё норм работает по этой статье

Comment: ещё один - https://simplecloud.ru/ - 180р/мес. Долго искал норм сервер, для бота. За минут 10 все встало, запело, заиграло. upd: пошел 7ой день работы бота, никаких проблем.

Answer (score 1):

*На удаленном сервере его запустить, т.е на хостинг залить*